# Getting the alt attribute value of an img tag using selenium

Tags: python, selenium

i'm very new to selenium and having a bit of trouble to extract the alt value from an img tag.
my html code :

```
<span class="logo">
<img src="url..........." alt="my logo">
</span>
```

python code : `driver.find_element_by_class_name("logo").find_element_by_xpath("//img").get_attribute('alt'))`

I also tried:

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name("logo").get_attribute('alt'))
```

and

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class='logo']//img").get_attribute('alt'))
```

and

```
span = driver.find_element_by_class_name("logo")
span.find_element_by_xpath("//img").get_attribute('alt')
```

I can print the objects but when i add the getAttribute() all of them return an empty string. Am i missing something? I tried to add alt = True in the find_element_by.....() method but it says unexpected argument! Can someone please explain what's happening here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: as @prophet says, a link to the page would help. It sounds like perhaps the image you are locating, the first that matches your specifications, might not have an alt attribute (because it might not be the one you think it is)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly you have to wait until the element is fully loaded before getting it attributes.
Also, I can't see any variable on the left side receiving the extracted attribute value in your code.
Try this:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

alt_val = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='logo']//img"))).get_attribute('alt'))

print(alt_val)
```

**UPD**
As I understand from your updates you are trying to extract the `alt` from retailers logos on the dialog presented by clicking the "Retailers" button.
If so the code will be as following:

```
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span.retlogo img")))
images = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("span.retlogo img")
for img in images:
    print(img.get_attribute('alt'))
```

Comment: I tried using time.sleep(5) before doing any operations and printed the value from get_attribute straight away so didn't store it anywhere. Will try the wait now

Comment: If you tried the same with sleeps this will not work as well...

Comment: can you share a link to the page?

Comment: hi sorry for the delay, i was trying to access the page - https://www.xbox.com/en-AU/consoles/xbox-series-x#purchase, then you press "CHECK AVAILABILITY" and then "SELECT A RETAILER" which will open a dialog box, i can extract the texts like price and stock details from the dialog box but not the "alt" attribute text from the logo

Comment: Do you mean the logos of retailers like "Amazon", "eb games" etc?

Comment: Yes I can access the img tag using the class name but no luck with for thr alt attribute

Comment: Did you try the updated answer? Your selector was wrong

Comment: hi sorry for the delay again but it worked! I can't thank you enough, would you kindly explain is it the only way to do it? I was following along an article and they mentioned i can pretty much find anything using the xpath and I didn't bother going through the rest of the article! Is there a way to achieve the same using xpath, and thanks heaps again.

Comment: Sure, the XPath equivalent for `span.retlogo img` css_selector is `//span[contains(@class,'retlogo')]//img`

Comment: so i need to add contains() while using xpath?

Comment: When you say `//span[@class='retlogo']` you are looking for element with `span` tag name and class attribute equals to `retlogo`. While `//span[contains(@class,'retlogo')]` means literally  element with `span` tag name and it contains class name `retlogo`.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to extract text is like this

```
driver.find_element("class name", "logo").find_element("tag name", "img").get_attribute("alt")
```