# Unable to extract alt text from <img> tags using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Im building a webscrape bot and I want to get the alt text of images from instagram posts. In theory this should not be that hard with .get_attribute('alt') command in Selenium but for some reason this never works. It always returns none.

Here's the code of my whole function:

```
def get_image_alt_text(posts):
alt_text = []
for link in posts:
    driver.get(link)
    time.sleep(4)
    try:
        image = driver.find_element(by=By.TAG_NAME, value="img")
        alt_text.append(image.get_attribute('alt'))
        print(alt_text)
    except:
        continue
return alt_text
```

when I run this it just puts an empty string into the list.
I also realize this isn't great code as there are usually multiple image tags on a page. So I rewrote it to find_elements() and then iterated every image on the page and none returned any alt text. Even though when inspecting the HTML on the site there is a value set for alt.

Comment: can you try `alt_text.append(image.get_attribute('innerHTML'))` or `alt_text.append(image.get_attribute('outerHTML'))` whichever has the string as per your element

Comment: What is the url of the page?

Comment: Maybe you need to wait for the element to fully load? [Related thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68399799/getting-the-alt-attribute-value-of-an-img-tag-using-selenium)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up getting around this issue by using .get_attribute('innerHTML') and then making a separate function to slice out the alt value from the given string.